# lambda func, s3 endpoint, and internet access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have a Lambda function in a VPC.  I also created an s3 endpoint.  The Lambda function is given the public subnet that has an internet gw attached to it.  It has no trouble accessing s3, but I cannot reach the internet to download some plugins.

When I remove the VPC, everything works fine with the lambda function.  I was just hoping to save costs by access s3 through the internal AWS routing.

I also looked at the route table for the public subnet:

- pl* for the s3 endpoints - working perfect
- 0.0.0.0/0 for igw - not working

BTW, I purposely am not using the NAT gw because it is sort of pricey when it is doing nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I apologized.  I forgot to follow.  Unlike ec2 instances, it's correct you need a NAT gateway since no public ip is associated with the lambda function though the control plane does assign it a private ip address in the vpc.  i have since corrected this with an inexpensive nat instance. thanks!